Baked textures look different to shader. Can anyone tell me why?
I created a material using a shader that has 3 resulting inputs: color, roughness and normals. I baked all three of those. However, when I replug those baked textures back into a material and apply it to the object, it looks different. I have found that the diffuse is the same but rough and normals are both different so they are the problem. I also notice a lot of noise on the final bake.
I have tried increasing samples up to 250 from 16. Using Optix and OED denoisers and finally increasing the individual textures from 1k to 2k and 4k.
I have attached a close up of both materials and a link to the file as the shader is quite complex so I cant upload a photo of it.
Original

Baked

blend file (Blender 3.6, 35 MB)
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1fCt8wvKNS7hRAIUf5IDY8nTXy8BwkuSq?usp=drive_link

More information than a single low-res screenshot hosted outside the site would be helpful in paring this down, as would information on what you've tried to pare it down yourself. Make a copy of the file. Delete things and re-test until you've got it down to the very simplest problem. Then, edit your question and share the file here with more details, please.

Ok, sorry. I am new to this. I will do as instructed. Thanks

@Phrogz. Hello, thanks for replying. Sorry I am new to this. I have done as instructed. Please let me know if you need more information.

I've reuploaded your file because there is only a one time download at https://file.io. -Please upload and embedd the images here so we don't have to click each link and accept cookies and so on.

@Blunder - Oh god that was freaking me out. I was unaware admins and such edited posts so I was thinking how do my posts keep changing. Sorry, I get it now. Thanks, I will do so in future :)

For the normal map, you have to use the Normal Map node. For the rest: it is missing the original textures, so it is just pink. Upload the blend file with the original textures packed.

@unwave. Great, that seems to have have bought back some missing details using the normal map node in between the baked normal and the bdsf. Oh very sorry about that, i was unaware it didn't include textures. I have packed and uploaded the new file.

Google changed the default setting for file sharing from Anyone with the link to Restricted quite a while ago. In the Google Drive file sharing options, you need to set it to Anyone with the link, otherwise one would need to request access.

@unwave oh god, they don't make it easy for us do they. I have changed the access settings. Thanks for letting me know.


The procedural normals give strange result because the Voronoi's position are not normal vectors, you need to use the Bump node to generate the actual normals.




The white parts: LeftBottomFlap, LeftTopFlap, RightBottomFlap and RightTopFlap are not baked at all and have overlapping UVs.



As mentioned, tangent space normal maps require the Normal Map node and like all non-color texture types the Color Space should be set to Non-Color.

Base Color, Roughness, Metallic, Alpha, Emission are better to be baked using Emit and the corresponding input of the Principled BSDF node. Normal can also be baked so, but it is non-trivial to set up the conversion. Other bake types such as Diffuse with only Color used for baking Base Color may not produce expected results. Cases where multiple shaders are mixed together give practically unpredictable results and should be first analytically converted to use only one Principled BSDF node.

Be aware of overlapping UVs. It is a valid approach when you want to reuse the texture space. But when baking, it is better to have only one copy of the overlapping parts in the 0-1 UVs space. Otherwise, the overlapping parts may corrupt the bake fighting between each other, making the bake less predictable.




When baking objects with modifiers, the settings of the modifiers that are used are the render ones, like in case with Subdivision Surface. The same goes for other settings in Blender, such as object render visibility. This will cause a discrepancy with how it looks in the viewport. So, make sure you have disabled for the render objects that can contribute to shader calculations, like in the case of Ambient Occlusion node, which is affected by all the visible at the render time geometry.



When saving the baked textures, make sure you use the right color space. The sockets: Base Color, Emission, Subsurface Color, Specular Tint, Coat Tint, Sheen Tint, Emission Color should be sRGB, the rest — Non-Color.

The denoiser works only for the Combined bake type.

After the bake you should compare the results with Cycles, the baker, not EEVEE as the results may differ, sometimes significantly.



Thank you for your answer. I have changed the normal setup of my shader nodes to match the one you have shown but this has quite significantly changed the visuals of my final material. I have tinkered but cannot seem to make it look like it did before? - I removed the flaps completely - the non-color image textures were done correctly as advised - I baked the base color and the roughness with emit instead but still looks different - I removed the modifier - After these changes. The baked material is still different? And also the original looks worse now with the new normal setup

You have hidden in the viewport objects that are enabled for the render, they affect the Ambient Occlusion node.

oh ok. I was unaware of that. I removed the flaps completely but ultimately the results are the same. The normal is a lot closer with the addition of the normal map but the roughness I'd quite different and alas the final image.

You would want to use the Smooth by Angle modifier, aka Auto Smooth, to make the normals better.  And the Bevel node will give beveled edges in the normal map.

Ok thanks and thank you for your help. Ultimately though it still isn't solved. It looks very different. I don't know what else to do.

Have you tried to delete or disable for render all other objects?

yeah i deleted every other mesh in the blender file. Just the gun remains. Also removed the overlapped UV's

I have downloaded the latest blend file from the Google Drive, removed the Subdivision Surface modifier and the results are: color, roughness, normal. 2k, 1 sample.

The normals look different because the shader ones are not normalized.
